# does logback support multiple configuration files

Tags: configuration-files, logback

if multiple XML configuration files exist in CLASSPATH, so what will happen? Just pick out a file randomly and ignore others, or the latter configuration overrides the former?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried, does not support multiple configuration files